# SQL Agent still attempting replication for deleted publication

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

We recently retired a replication publication, deleting each subscription (push subscriptions) and then deleting the publication, all from within SSMS.  However, we continue to get the following message (once every minute) in the four days since deleting this publication.

> Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent (null) failed. The publication 'Replicate_ASG_Reference_Data' does not exist.

Why is it still trying to run a deleted publication, and how do I stop it?

Additional information: This is on SQL Server 2008 SP3 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue never resolved.  We dealt with this until migrating to SQL 2012 in October 2013.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some orphaned replication bits and/or orphaned replication agent jobs.

Note that Distribution.dbo.sp_MSremove_published_jobs **will not** remove your Distribution Agent jobs.  You will have to manually delete the orphaned job(s).

Locate the job(s) under SQL Server Agent -> Jobs.  The Distribution Agent job names will have the format **Publisher-PublicationDatabase-Publication-Subscriber-integer**.  Right-click the job -> Delete.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, we had three replication publications (2 snapshot, one transactional) on the database; we removed one (snapshot replication) but the other two continue in use.  It's a non-trivial matter, operationally and procedurally (business-wise) to remove the database from replication.

Comment: Then just manually delete the orphaned Distribution Agent job(s).  That will clear up your error.

Answer (score 2):

Funny answer to this one for me.  One of the subscribers was still attempting to connect to this publication.  Once I found it, I deleted it and all was good in the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You have to properly clean up replication using :

```
sp_removedbreplication 'database_name'
```

Since you dont need replication, you can delete the associated jobs as well on the distribution server.

---

EDIT : Since you have to remove snapshot replication only from the current database which is being used for T-REP as well, follow below steps :

At publisher database :

```
sp_droppublication  @publication=  'publication_to_Drop'
```

At subscriber datatabase :

```
sp_subscription_cleanup [ @publisher = ] 'publisher'
        , [ @publisher_db = ] 'publisher_db'
    [ , [ @publication = ] 'publication']
```

Refer to [kb324401](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/replication/manually-remove-replication)

---

Manually or using T-SQL :

```
exec Distribution.dbo.sp_MSremove_published_jobs @server = 'PublicationServer', 
@database = 'replicated_DB_NAME'
```

Also refer to : [Steps to clean up orphaned replication settings in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2710/steps-to-clean-up-orphaned-replication-settings-in-sql-server/) and [How to cleanup Replication Bits](https://repltalk.com/2010/11/17/how-to-cleanup-replication-bits/)

Comment: Unfortunately, we had three replication publications (2 snapshot, one transactional) on the database; we removed one (snapshot replication) but the other two continue in use.  It's a non-trivial matter, operationally and procedurally (business-wise) to remove the database from replication.

Comment: Then you have to clean up replication bits for snapshot replication ONLY as I have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, this is how I solved it

1. find running job `NAME` with this somewhere in command `'Replicate_ASG_Reference_Data'`
   use this SQL:

   ```
   USE master
   GO
   SELECT job.job_id,name,command
   FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs job 
     INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps ON job.job_id = steps.job_id
   WHERE job.enabled = 1 AND command LIKE '%ASG%'
   ```
2. this SQL will show 1 or more jobs which have this in command, find offending one and disable/delete job